# Extremely slow connection after 17.04 update

Tags: networking, 17.04

My connection has become extremely slow after I updated to 17.04. It was fine in 16.10.

Chrome gets stuck at "Resolving host..." for sometimes more than 30 seconds. I've tried other browsers and they are the same. Meanwhile my phone which is connected to the same network is fast as usual.

I have tried adding following lines to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` but it didn't change anything:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Comment: For what it's worth I also have this problem. My wifi connection is unbearably slow, but the problem persists even when wired. This is a brand new install of 17.04, so it shouldn't be an upgrade problem.

Comment: @MarkRoberts I think I have found a workaround. Go to network settings. Under IPv4 tab, pick the second option as `Method` and enter a static DNS address. Also check `Require IPv4 for this connection to complete` if it doesn't work. I tried with Google DNS (8.8.8.8) and it seems OK for now.

Comment: Maybe related to this? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1656830

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Network`? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Hi, I think the issue was solved with an update. At least for me.

Answer (score 9):

I had the exact same issue (just like @Mark Roberts).

Here is the fix:

Note: the current `/etc/resolv.conf` file is actually a symlink to `../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` which appears to be the core issue since it is not maintained by systemd-resolved.

Thus if you do an `ls -la` you'll see:

```
~# ls -la /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 29 Apr 14 11:36 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

so... to get around this do the following:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

After that I kicked systemd-resolved just to make sure:

`sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved`

This appears to work great because:

> systemd-resolved maintains the /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf file
>   for compatibility with traditional Linux programs. This file may be
>   symlinked from /etc/resolv.conf and is always kept up-to-date,
>   containing information about all known DNS servers.

Which I quoted DIRECTLY from the [bug report:(bug # 1624320)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1624320) and I believe it is the culprit.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this discussion](https://github.com/cpriego/valet-linux/issues/7) which blames systemd-resolv (something to do with DNS) and suggests the workaround of setting DNSSEC=off in resolved.conf

The exact same workaround has just been released to the Zesty repositories: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1682499

So long story short: Run Software Updater right now. Maybe that will solve the issue...

Comment: Doesn't anyone test it before the release? This is the most obvious bug I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

I never had problems with Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS but tried Ubuntu 17.04 and adding `gnome-session`, and that's when problems started. I was hoping to move to Ubuntu and enjoy Ubuntu Upgrade to 17.10 with Gnome DM, but alas:

- Spotty wifi
- Slow Internet (Wired and WiFi)
- Apps installing at 60-90% ... not finishing for 10's of minutes! or not at all

**My solution after trying many workarounds was to install a fresh Ubuntu GNOME 17.04.**

And how do I know that LightDM was the culprit? Well, in my frustration at video tearing, someone suggested LightDM is much better (for the moment - a vsync issue) so I installed it. I logged back in with LightDM and... yep, ridiculous internet issues.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for this!

> I realized that this issue was originating from a service called ‘systemd-resolved’. This is a DNS caching and validating service that comes pre-installed with Ubuntu 17.04.

The complete Solution is [in this article](https://www.hecticgeek.com/2017/04/ubuntu-17-04-systemd-dns-issues/) (half way down is the updated version)

Here are my simple notes for the commands (perhaps helpful but the above website does a great job)

```
service NetworkManager status
head /etc/resolv.conf
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

change `nameserver 127.0.0.1` to `nameserver 8.8.8.8`

```
sudo apt-get install unbound
```

Now let’s disable the troublesome `systemd-resolved`

```
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Change to `dns=unbound`

```
sudo systemctl enable unbound-resolvconf
service NetworkManager status
reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

In 17.10, it should not be `off` in `resolved.conf`:

```
DNSSEC=off
```

Just setting it to `no` solves it.

```
DNSSEC=no
```

It is in the file by default but commented out (with a leading `#`).