# Ubuntu 17.04 network slowness if both eth and wifi are connected

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet, realtek, iwlwifi

I just upgraded from 16.10 to 17.04 and I started to have network problems when connected to my office's network.

I can connect to my office network with eth or wifi, both ways are working well by themselves. But with 17.04, if I have wifi connected at the same time as the cable, the network is extremely slow. If I disconnect any of them, the network is fast as ever.

Both methods connect to the same network (in my case 10.10.1.0/24). I have dhcp assigning me fixed ip addresses based on mac address.

Having read [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/905288/extremely-slow-connection-after-17-04-update), I just ran software-updater, but I was already up-to-date.

My network-info is [pasted here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24814295/).

Any ideas on what should I look for?

Answer (score 0):

I might be going out on a limb here but I'm going to say that Wi-Fi and Ethernet shouldn't be on the same subnet, as this will cause routing problems.

Try using different subnets for Wifi and Ethernet interfaces.

Are you using Ubuntu Network Manager or /etc/network/interfacas to manage your devices?

Comment: I've been using this setup (wifi and ethernet) for several years now with no routing problems. But I agree that might be the case. I'll try to debug the packet flow with tcpdump...  I'm using network-manager.